# How to make an RDD from the first n items of another RDD in Spark?

Tags: pyspark

Given an RDD in pyspark, I would like to make a new RDD which only contains (a copy of) its first n items, something like:

`n=100
rdd2 = rdd1.limit(n)`

except RDD does not have a method `limit()`, like DataFrame does.

Note that I do not want to collect the result, the result must still be an RDD, therefore I cannot use `RDD.take()`.

I am using pyspark 2.44.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the RDD to a DF limit and convert it back

```py
rdd1.toDF().limit(n).rdd
```